# Magento 2 : Change product price while moving to cart event and observer

Tags: magento2, cart, event-observer

I have created a custom module

> but moving to cart
>
> I want to add a custom price

**which event i can use to change the price**

> how to change product price while moving to cart event and observer Magento 2

Comment: Hi bro, what is the reason to change the price?

Comment: i have customized to some customers to price change but only
changing price in catelog

Comment: @prabhakaran7 if some customers are in same group, can you use cart price rules...

Comment: @prabhakaran7 Is it working for you?

Comment: nope..............